# My semodule is not working

Tags: linux, selinux

I has installed setools and selinux-policy-devel,but when I want to load a module,I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQlCx.png)

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a permission denied error, have you tried the operation as the root user?

Comment: Yeah，I have tried the operation as the root user.But,it doesn`t work.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output when running it as root please?

Comment: OK.The output is like this: ![output](http://a1.qpic.cn/psb?/V13YH7W402XUsU/.XDeDOkGy9aFeUGNTn0GYoAU2p0htFqmhNbTFzUMb*M!/b/dBcBAAAAAAAA&bo=3ALTAAAAAAADBy8!&rf=viewer_4),and  I find that the `/var/lib/selinux/targeted/active/modules` is empty.As a result ,the output of `semodule -l` is `no modules`.

Comment: How did you obtain your pp file?  Did you use `audit2allow` utility to create it?  Can you post your `te` file?